# What is $a^{(\log_ab)^2}$?

Tags: logarithms

Can the following expression be further simplified: $$a^{(\log_ab)^2}?$$

I know for example that $$a^{\log_ab^2}=b^2.$$

Comment: $$a^{mn}=(a^m)^n$$  $ m=n\implies?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$a^{(\log_ab)^2}=a^{\log_a(b)\times \log_a(b)}=b^{\log_a(b)}$$

Comment: What's so wrong with this ?...

Comment: Although, I did not vote down, but are you sure this is correct?

Comment: This probably isn't, but I'd like an explanation before I remove it for good, just so I don't make the same mistake in the future. I'm genuinely confused.

Comment: If $\log_a b$ is a real number (as we can suppose from OP) it seems correct to me.

Comment: Unless otherwise explicitly stated, these questions should, imo, be considered as asking about the real, standard logarithm, and thus this answer is correct. Of course, it must be $\;a,b>0\,,\,\,a\neq1\;$ and etc. Whoever downvoted was trolling around (there are quite a few around...), or was just bored, or just couldn't understand this answer. +1

Answer (score 3):

Use:

- $$\log_x(y)=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(x)}$$
- $$\exp\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]=e^{\ln(x)}=x$$

---

So, we get:

$$a^{\left(\log_a(b)\right)^2}=a^{\left(\frac{\ln(b)}{\ln(a)}\right)^2}=a^{\frac{\ln^2(b)}{\ln^2(a)}}=\exp\left[\frac{\ln^2(b)}{\ln(a)}\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

$$a^{(\log_ab)^2}=a^{\log_a b\cdot \log_a b}=(a^{\log_a b})^{\log_a b}=b^{\log_a b}=b^{\frac{1}{\log_b a}}.$$

Comment: Is $\log_{a} {b} = -\log _{b}{a}$ ?